# Copy lines in visual mode in vim

Tags: vim, copy-paste

Just a question about copy/paste workflow in gVim.

Right now I'm working on a document. I want to select some lines of code and copy and paste. I'm using gVim (Windows).

If I use Control + C and Control + V, gVim takes sometimes 2, 3 seconds to paste...

The other way is using, Shift + v (right, now I'm in visual mode), then I keep the Shift key pressed and drag my selection with the mouse. Now I can copy with 'y' or 'c' and paste with 'p'. This is faster, but I have to keep the Shift key pressed.

Is there a way to use the mouse to select text in visual mode without keeping the Shift key pressed? I want to use y/d/p instead of slow Control + c and Control + v. Is there a better workflow or setup that I should try?

Thanks,

[]'s

Mateus

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Stay away from using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> and your mouse in `vim`, or at least until you're familiar with `vim`'s way of text handling.

--

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to enter visual line mode

[image]

Press `3j` to go down 3 lines, or press `j` 3 times

[image]

`y` to yank/copy, `x` to cut, `p` to paste after cursor, `P` to paste before cursor.

[image]

Using <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> will improve your workflow greatly as you don't have to move your hands from the typing position to the arrows and the mouse.

There are a couple of ways to yank multiple lines without entering visual mode. One of which is to type `<action><number><direction>`. For example, `y3j` means to yank from your current row to 3 rows down.

If you want to yank the entire paragraph or sentence you're in, type `yip` (yank IN paragraph) or `yis` (yank IN sentence) respectively. You can also do `yi"` (yank IN `"`) or `ya"` (yank AROUND `"`) to yank everything that's surrounded by `"` on your current position.

Comment: Hi Jin, thanks! It's not easy to 'unlearn' the mouse... I try your method and find out other way.

Comment: @homemrobo It wasn't easy for me too.. but I feel that it is worth it at the end. Took me about a week or two to learn enough essentials to get away from the mouse :p

Comment: Fun Fact: The yanked lines can not be pasted anywhere else or in vim on another machine.
Figured out when I yanked (still not comfortable with this term) some lines on Vim on a remote server and tried pasting those in Vim on my local machine.