# How to copy selected lines to clipboard in vim

Tags: vim

How to copy selected lines to clipboard in vim. I know how to do it for [all text files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1620018/1082727), but I want to do in for selected lines.
Thanks!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694633/copy-lines-using-visual-mode-in-vim, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961859/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-using-vim

Comment: see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cut/copy_and_paste_using_visual_selection

Comment: Note to anyone encountering this: None of these answers work if you don't have clipboard support with vim, check with `vim --version | grep clip`, the only option is to uninstall vim and install gvim and use vim as you normally would. `vim`

Answer (score 155, accepted):

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> puts you in select lines mode. Then <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> yanks the currently selected lines to the `+` register which is the clipboard. There are [quite a few](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers) different registers, for different purposes. See the section on `selection and drop registers` for details on the differences between `*` and `+` registers on Windows and Linux. Note that there is only a distinction between "* and "+ for X11 systems. Under MS-Windows, use of "* and "+ is actually synonymous and refers to the gui-clipboard. So, on windows `*` (sharp) register can be used as well: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

Comment: In Linux, + is global clipboard, * is selection clipboard, while in Windows both map to global clipboard.

Comment: This works for me when I'm selecting just a few lines, but when I select multiple *pages* of lines, and try `"+y`, the lines don't make it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 84):

If you're on Linux and are using a VIm version 7.3.74 or higher (the version that gets installed in Ubuntu 11.10 onwards satisfies this), you can do

`set clipboard=unnamedplus`

which will place yanked text into the global clipboard, and allow you to paste from the global clipboard, without having to use any special registers. Unlike ldigas's solution, this will also work on non-gui versions of VIm.

Comment: This only works if I install the `vim-gnome` package instead of `vim`.

Comment: @dan-klasson: this option requires a vim that was compiled with clipboard support. You can check if this is the case by typing `vim --version | grep "+xterm_clipboard"`.

Comment: This seems to work to copy into other non-vim programs, but when I go into insert mode in vim and use "shift + insert" to paste from the clipboard, only the first two lines get pasted... I installed vim-gnome; am I missing something else?

Comment: If you're on macOS you'll probably need to use `clipboard=unnamed` instead (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard)

Answer (score 16):

For GVIM, hit `v` to go into visual mode; select text and hit `Ctrl+Insert` to copy selection into global clipboard.

From the menu you can see that the shortcut key is `"+y` i.e. hold Shift key, then press `"`, then `+` and then release Shift and press `y` (cumbersome in comparison to Shift+Insert).

Comment: Why is this answer not popular? :(

Answer (score 13):

```
set guioptions+=a
```

will, ... uhmm, in short, whenever you select/yank something put it in the clipboard as well (not Vim's, but the global keyboard of the window system). That way you don't have to think about yanking things into a special register.

Comment: // , To which operating systems and/or versions of Vim does this advice apply?

Answer (score 12):

First check if your vim installation has clipboard support.

```
vim --version
```

If clipboard support is installed you will see:

```
+clipboard
+X11
+xterm_clipboard
```

If clipboard support is not installed you will see:

```
-clipboard
-X11
-xterm_clipboard
```

To install clipboard support:

```
apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Once you have verified that clipboard support is installed do the following:

1. Position your cursor to the first line you want to copy.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to enter visual mode.
3. Press <kbd>↓</kbd> to select multiple lines
4. Press <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to copy the selected text to system clipboard.
5. Now you can copy the selected text to browser, text editor etc.
6. Press <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> if you want to copy system clipboard text to vim.

Above steps might get tedious if you have to repeatedly copy from vim to system clipboard and vice versa.
You can create vim shortcuts so that when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> selected text will be copied to system clipboard. And when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> system clipboard text is copied to vim. To create shortcuts :

1. Open .vimrc file and add following text at the end of file:

   ```
    nnoremap <C-c> "+y
    vnoremap <C-c> "+y
    nnoremap <C-p> "+p
    vnoremap <C-p> "+p
   ```
2. Save and reload your .vimrc to apply the new changes.
3. Position your cursor to the first line you want to copy.
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to enter visual mode.
5. Press <kbd>↓</kbd> to select multiple lines
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to copy the selected text to system clipboard.
7. Now you can copy the selected text to browser, text editor etc.
8. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> if you want to copy system clipboard text to vim.

Note: This is for ubuntu systems.

Comment: In newer version of ubuntu/mint `sudo apt-get install vim-gtk3`

Answer (score 7):

Install "xclip" if you haven't...

`sudo apt-get install xclip`

Xclip puts the data into the "selection/highlighted" clipboard that you middle-click to paste as opposed to "ctrl+v"

While in vim use ex commands:

```
7w !xclip
```

or

```
1,7w !xclip
```

or

```
%w !xclip
```

Then just middle-click to paste into any other application...

Comment: I had to use `xclip -selection clipboard`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using vim in MAC OSX, unfortunately it comes with older verion, and not complied with clipboard options. Luckily, homebrew can easily solve this problem.

**install vim:**

`brew install vim --with-lua --with-override-system-vim`

**install gui verion of vim:**

`brew install macvim --with-lua --with-override-system-vim`

restart the terminal to take effect.

append the following line to ~/.vimrc

`set clipboard=unnamed`

now you can copy the line in vim with`yy`
and paste it system-wide.

Comment: // , I just tested this on OSX 10.12.3, and it worked properly after I installed both the latest Vim and the latets GUI version of Vim, as you recommended here. Thanks, @anonymous.

Answer (score 5):

If vim is compiled with clipboard support, then you can use `"*y` meaning: yank visually selected text into register `*` ('*' is for clipboard)

If there is no clipboard support, I think only other way is to use `Ctrl+Insert` after visually selecting the text in vim.

Answer (score 3):

I have added the following line to my `.vimrc`

```
vnoremap <F5> "+y<CR>
```

This allows you to copy the *selected text* to the clipboard by pressing `F5`. You must be in visual mode for this to work.

Comment: Add to `~/.vimrc` Thank you, this is much better.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code into your `.vimrc`:

```
if has('clipboard')
    if has('unnamedplus')  " When possible use + register for copy-paste
        set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus
    else         " On mac and Windows, use * register for copy-paste
        set clipboard=unnamed
    endif
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps that would work:

1. Open source file in vim.
2. Go to visual mode by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>
3. Select the number of lines by moving the up/down arrow keys.
4. Once text to be copied is highlighted, then yank (copy) it to + register by pressing following keys: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>
5. Now open target file in vim.
6. Paste the text copied in step 4 in to target file by pressing: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

After some helpful comments on this thread I decided to add my own setup, which works great so far:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('v', '<C-C>', '"+y', { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('v', '<C-X>', '"+ygv<DEL>', { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

I just select in visual mode and press known to everyone Ctrl+C. If I want to also delete it, I press Ctrl+X. Basically that's how it works in all modern editors, and it's imo more performant than vim's modal commands, so why not?

Note that this config is in `lua`. I highly recommend using it over vimscript, it is much richer.

Comment: you are god amongst men. From this mouse using heretic, have an upvote Sir!