# Copy from Vim visual mode to system clipboard

Tags: vim

I want to copy text from visual mode into system (Ubuntu) clipboard. When I do `ggVG` to select everything in Vim, I can't seem to copy that into system clipboard.

Now I read several options on how to do this, but none of them works. For example this does not work:
`"+y` or `"+` or `"*yy`

Why is it not working?

Comment: checkout my answere here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666057/9384511

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably using the default Vim. It's a lightweight build that lacks a number of features including clipboard support.

You can verify that with this command:

```
:echo has('clipboard')
```

`O` (zero) means "no clipboard support".

The simplest way to get clipboard support is to install a proper build:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Then, you'll be able to do `"+y` and `"+p`.

See `:help 'clipboard'` for a way to synchronize Vim's unnamed register and your system clipboard.

Comment: Yep, it didn't have clipboard support! Now installed like you said and it works, thank you sir.