# How to copy a selected word to the clipboard using VIM?

Tags: vim, clipboard

I would like to copy a selected word that the cursor is on to the clipboard. Is there a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If support for clipboard is built into your Vim, clipboard is mapped to register *, so you use it the same as any other register. So, for example, to copy the word under cursor to clipboard you do `"*yiw`. To copy current line `"*yy`. To paste from clipboard `"*p`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want to do this:

```
viwp
```

which will visually select a new word, and paste over it.

Now, if you don't want to lose your register when doing this, you can also put in your vimrc:

```
xnoremap p pgvy
```

Answer (score 1):

First at all you must check if the clipboard feature on your VIM is enable or not. For that use the --version parameter (vim --version)

If not (-clipboard), you can use a gtk vim edition or compile VIM manually. 
If yes (+clipboard), in normal mode `"+yiw` on your word for copy it in your clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Follow instruction in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666057/9384511

Once you have set up your vim as per above link, you will be able to copy single or multiple lines from vim to clipboard by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>. And paste from clipboard to vim by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

Now to copy just a single word to clipboard press <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>