# How do I use marks (not visual selection) to copy to the system clipboard on vim?

Tags: vim

[Most](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9166328/9636) [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15971506/9636) of copying to the system clipboard from vim involve using visual selection. I don't want to do that because I have to copy text that spans multiple screens. It's faster for me to use marks.

If I was just yanking the lines, I'd do:

```
/<<<<< # find the beginning of my diff
ma     # set mark `a` to the current position
/===== # find the end of my diff
y'a    # yank all lines between the current position and mark `a`.
```

I presume there's some way to `y'a` into a specific register, or transfer from the [unnamed register](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers) to the selection register `*`.

Comment: `set clipboard=unnamedplus,autoselect,exclude:cons\\\\|linux`

Comment: Isn't that just `"*y'a`?

Comment: No. My Mac OS X 10.11.6 default vim dings at me when I do `"*` I don't even get to the `y'a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
:'a,.y *
```

or (shorter):

```
:'a,y *
```

See `:help :y`.